# Load Database or make request

Tags: c++, database, performance, sqlite

I have a sqlite database with only one table and I would like to know if it's better to load all my data at the beginning and save it in map or vector or whatever or just make simple request. I have only 255 line in my table.

Comment: "_I would like to know if it's better to load all my data at the beginning and save it in map or vector or whatever or just make simple request._" What's your definition of "better"?

Comment: For nearly all aspects of 'better', you should just work with the database in real time. SQLite is already pretty fast and crash-resistant.

Comment: I should have said faster than better

Answer (score 1):

load all my data at the beginning

PRO:

- faster
- code is simpler, so long as **data does not change**

CON:

- if data changes, you need to organize synchronization the two copies.